# rails parse push notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification

Im playing around with Recurly, the app enables real time push notifications.
My question is what is best pratice and how do I parse the incomming XML, the XML look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<new_account_notification>
  <account>
    <account_code>verena@test.com</account_code>
    <username></username>
    <email>verena@test.com</email>
    <first_name>Verena</first_name>
    <last_name>Test</last_name>
    <company_name></company_name>
  </account>
</new_account_notification>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the XML to a hash with the Hash.from_xml method, and then work with the resulting hash.

```
notification_hash = Hash.from_xml(recurly_xml)
```

Comment: That's how I'm doing it, specifically with: post = Hash.from_xml(request.body())

Comment: How and where do you get "request.body()" or recurly_xml in the code?

Comment: Rails provides the request object - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html.   The recurly notification will pass the recurly xml, so you'll have to get it from the params object.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Recurly and options for working with it in Rails, but [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is a very nice gem for parsing and handling XML and HTML.

```
# assuming push_notification contains the XML
doc = Nokogiri::XML(push_notification)

# do stuff with the parsed XML
email = doc.xpath("/new_account_notification/account/email").text
```